# Automatically display the next step after filling in the inputs

Tags: javascript

I have these fields that are populated in two steps.
1.How can I make it so that after filling in the fields in step 1, step 2 opens automatically.
2.The fields of step 1 must be filled in yes or yes and you cannot advance to step 2 without first fulfilling that condition

I'm learning js, how could I achieve this goal

```
<style>
output {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
    transition: grid-template-rows 0.125s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    min-height: 0;
}

.ocultar_check {
    display: none;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+output {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    display: grid;
    gap: 0.2rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.pasos {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #1E1E1E;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.125s;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;

    &:hover {
        background: oklch(0.8 0 0.1);
    }
}

.error-border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<fieldset id="accordion">
    <label for="1" class="pasos">Step1</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="1" value="1" checked>
    <output>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="name" id="name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="last name" id="last_name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="phone" id="phone" name="" required />
        </div>
    </output>
    <label for="2" class="pasos">Step2</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="2" value="2">
    <output>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="city" id="city" name="" required />
        </div>
    </output>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I understand you are learning, but this is a place for help, not for getting the work done for you. Next time, please detail what you have tried and provide any code.

As I said, you mentioned you are learning JS, but provided no JS code - so it appears you haven't tried anything yourself and are just here looking for a free answer/free work.

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that I would suggest a different approach by showing the full form or create(use) a card like fill-out form. The approach here's to launch a timeout each time there's an input, but only run the function after a certain `delay`.

```
<script>
  const input1 = document.getElementById('phone')
  const input2 = document.getElementById('2')

  input1.addEventListener('input', goToNextTab)

  let goToTheNextTabTimeout = undefined
  const delay = 2000;

  function goToNextTab() {
    clearTimeout(goToTheNextTabTimeout)
    goToTheNextTabTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      input2?.click();
    }, delay);
  }
</script>
```